# Crear .exe para código python pyinstaller, cx_freeze, etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy utilizando estas librerias para una GUI, necesito crear un ejecutable para windows, estoy trabajando con windows 7 32bits.
utilice pyinstaller, si me corre el programa pero al correrlo me abre el proceso detras de la GUI (una ventana negra), el archivo que uso para la GUI es .pyw pero aun así me hace esto.

También utilicé cx_freeze pero no me corre la aplicación.

¿Alguna solución para lo que ocurre con pyinstaller o alguna otra librería para crear un ejecutable?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import threading
import time
from tkinter import *
```

Comment: Le has pasado la opcion `windowed`: `pyinstaller script.py --windowed`?

Comment: gracias, utilice la opcion windowed y quedo perfecto.

Comment: @eyllanesc considera añadirlo como respuesta :)